# An uncaught Exception was encountered in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function file_exits()

Filename: C:\wamp64\www\blog\application\controllers\Pages.php

Line Number: 7

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp64\www\blog\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller
{
    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
     if(!file_exits(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
     {show_404();}
    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page,$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: You made a typo in the name of the function. You wrote `file_exits` while the function is called `file_exists`.
Also, please provide a bit more verbal context for the questions if you can! Pasting an error message is not really the best way.

Comment: @Isti115 is correct. Try going through your code as well and the error it's showing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo. `file_exits()` ? It should be `file_exists()`. Voting to close.